# How to make a really nice leaderboard embed with Discord XP

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord, discord.js

This is my current code its pretty basic, I would love to know how to make the leaderboard something like this:

[image]

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Levels = require("discord-xp");
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args, queue, searcher) => {
    const rawLeaderboard = await Levels.fetchLeaderboard(message.guild.id, 5);
    if (rawLeaderboard.length < 1) return reply("Nobody's in leaderboard yet.");

    const leaderboard = await Levels.computeLeaderboard(client, rawLeaderboard);

    const lb = leaderboard.map((e) => `${e.position}. ${e.username}#${e.discriminator}\nLevel: ${e.level}\nXP: ${e.xp.toLocaleString()}`);

    message.channel.send(`${lb.join("\n\n")}}`);
};

module.exports.config = {
    name: "leaderboard",
    aliases: ["lb"],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer to above question and would like to help you out with it since i had to search a lot to get the answer.

I used the code underneath to get a nice leaderboard and also tags the user in the leaderboard:

```
const lb = leaderboard.map(e => `**#${e.position}** **<@${e.userID}>**\nLevel: \`${e.level}\`\nXP: \`${(e.xp - Levels.xpFor(e.level))}/${(Levels.xpFor(e.level + 1) - Levels.xpFor(e.level))}\``)
```

Let me know if it is the fix that you are searching for!